# How to get which radio button is selected in symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, radio-button, symfony-3.3

I have these inputs in my twig file :

```
<input type="text" name="txtNom" id="txtNom" value="{{user.nom}}"  />
<input type="text" name="txtPrenom" id="txtPrenom" value="{{user.prenom}}"  />

<input type="radio" name="rbSexe" id="rbHomme" onclick="changeGender(this.id);" />
<input type="radio" name="rbSexe" id="rbFemme" onclick="changeGender(this.id);" />
```

So, for calling those inputs in my Controller, I use the name attribute, for the first two  it's okay :

```
$utilisateur->setNom($request->get('txtNom'));
$utilisateur->setPrenom($request->get('txtPrenom'));
```

but those with radio type have the same name, so how can I call specific one of them?

```
$utilisateur->setSexe(?????????);
```

Comment: radio buttons are intended to have the same name but different values, so the question would be how are you defining those values in your HTML?

Comment: @fyrye Thanks, but I solved the problem ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem :

I give the inputs a value, and make the name looks like an array:

```
<input type="radio" name="rbSexe[]" value="Homme" id="rbHomme" onclick="changeGender(this.id);" />
<input type="radio" name="rbSexe[]" value="Femme" id="rbFemme" onclick="changeGender(this.id);" />
```

and for call it in Controller, I use this :

```
$s = $request->get('rbSexe',0)[0];
```